# Wildfire vs Apps

Tags: facebook

please excuse the beginner question but my research here shows nothing but specific programming questions.

I am currently using Wildfire app to create fb pages for contests and whatnot but don't like the WYSIWYG nature of them. I would like to be able to build pages within Facebook to have more control over their layouts and design.

Is anyone here familiar with Wildfire app and could you please explain to me how one would break away from 3rd party apps like this?

**On the same note:**
Without going crazy trying to create fb games deeply rooted in facebook, is it possible to build fb pages/apps such as sweepstakes, contests which may or may not post to users walls using only html/css/javascript?
Or is one forced to be a PHP developer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don’t want to use 3rd party apps any more, then naturally that means creating your own apps.

You don’t necessarily need PHP or any server-side scripting language – at least *most* of the stuff you can do in apps can be done client-side as well. (There are only a few aspects, f.e. when publishing Open Graph actions you can specify that the publishing can only be done using the app secret – that means no one can “fake” publish an action as coming from your app, but it also requires to be done server-side, because you do not want to publish your app secret to the client. And the same for any other requests that will *require* your app token – you don’t want to give that away to the client either.)

But you will still need web hosting that has a valid SSL certificate. (And having your own domain as well is recommendable, because there’s always threads here about people getting user access to their apps blocked because the whole domain they are running their apps under is classified as being spammy by Facebook, even if its not their own fault.)

Comment: Great thank you so much for the help and info. Can I ask though, why would I want my own domain for creation of apps on Facebook? Is it because the contests and sweepstakes pages are actually on my own site and being pulled into Facebook via an iframe?

Comment: Yes, the content of every canvas/page tab app is displayed in an iframe, and the pages are laying on a different webserver somewhere. The advice about getting your own domain was just for the mentioned reason of possible blockage of a whole domain by Facebook for spam – you don’t _need_ your own domain though.